Preimage commutes with intersections (is my proof correct?) - Bert Mendelson introduction to topology page $14$ Question $4(b)$
I want to check if the following proof is correct. The proof online, which can be found here, is a bit longer, so maybe my proof is not correct. Other than it's overall brevity, is my proof lacking any important details?
Let $f:A\to B$ be given and let $\{Y_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an indexed family of subsets of $B.$
Prove $f^{-1} \left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} Y_{\alpha}\right)=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}f^{-1}\left(Y_{\alpha}\right).$
Proof $x\in f^{-1} \left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} Y_{\alpha}\right)\iff f(x)\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}Y_{\alpha}\iff f(x)\in Y_{\alpha}\ \forall\ \alpha\in I\iff x\in f^{-1}(Y_{\alpha})\ \forall\ \alpha\in I\iff x\in\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}f^{-1}\left(Y_{\alpha}\right).$

In particular, I am unsure if I have used either of the incorrect statements,
$$X= f^{-1}(f(X)) \text{ for any } X\in A$$
(correct is $X\subset f^{-1}(f(X)) \text{ for any } X\in A$), or,
$$X= f(f^{-1}(Y))=Y \text{ for any } Y\in B$$
(correct is $Y\subset f(f^{-1}(Y)) \text{ for any } Y\in B$).


It seems to me that your proof is correct and rigorous.

I’m voting to close this question because you asked for "solution-verification". Tag-description "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions. " Your question does not satisfy this requirement.

I suggest you improve your title. Eg “preimage commutes with intersections” (is my proof correct). People should (a) be able to search for your question and (b) see roughly at a glance from the main page what your question is about
